# Choosing the right Angular2 Lifecycle

Tags: angular

I have the following code:

```
<view-user *ngIf="selectedUser" [userID]="selectedUser.id"></view-user>
```

and an API call: `loadUser(userID)` in my `view-user` component, in the

```
ngOnInit()
```

whenever the selectedUser is changed, the ngOnInit is not being called and the  layout is not changing. it means I see the same user although the selectedUser is different.

I believe the `ngOnInit()` is  called only in the first time, and after that the variable changes but the ngOnInit() is not being callede anymore.

How I can run my `loadUser()` method whenever the `userID` is changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a setter to change your userID:

```
private _userID: number;

get userID() {
  return this._userID;
}

@Input()
set userID(userID: number) {
  this._userID = userID;
  loadUser(userID);
}
```

Or you can use the [`ngOnChanges` method](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html#!#onchanges).